# scala: make a function tail recursive

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have the following function in scala:

```
def is_in[T](e: T, as: List[T]) : Boolean = as match
{
  case Nil => false;
  case x::xs => e == x || is_in(e, xs);
}
```

Now I want to make this function tail recursive. My idea is the following:

```
// tail recursive:

def is_in[T](e: T, as:List[T]) : Boolean =
{
  @tailrec
  def is_in_tailrec[T](e: T, as:List[T], acc: Boolean) : Boolean =
  {
    as match
    {
      case Nil => acc;
      case x::xs => is_in_tailrec(... here I got stuck ...);
    }
  }
  is_in_tailrec(e, as, 1);
}
```

Could someone please give me an advice how I can make this function tail recursive?

Comment: It already is tail recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion is

```
{
    case Nil => acc
    case _ if acc => acc
    case x :: xs => is_in_tailrec(e, xs, x == e)
}
```

or may be even

```
{
    case x :: xs if !acc => is_in_tailrec(e, xs, x == e)
    case _ => acc
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the one who posted the answer with the helper method which was similar to my version deleted his post. I just wanted to analyse that and see what my mistakes are ...

Comment: @seas in his version acc was always false, may be he realised it - thats why...this one is also for your version, i just publiched it partially

Answer (score 5):

Actually you don't need the helper method with accumulator here. Just check if `e == x` returns `false`, then call the method with the rest of the list, otherwise return true:

```
  def is_in[T](e: T, as: List[T]): Boolean = as match {
    case Nil => false
    case x :: _ if e == x => true
    case _ :: xs => is_in(e, xs)
  }
```

Comment: You don't even need to do this, the function is already tail recursive as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is already tail recursive. If you mark it as `@annotation.tailrec` it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why the one who posted the answer with the helper method which was similar to my version deleted his post. I just wanted to analyse that and see what my mistakes are ...

I guess you meant

```
def is_in[T](e: T, as: List[T]) : Boolean = {
  @tailrec
  def is_in_tailrec[T](e: T, as: List[T], acc: Boolean): Boolean = as match {
    case Nil     => acc
    case x :: xs => is_in_tailrec(e, xs, e == x || acc)
  }

  is_in_tailrec(e, as, false)
}
```

Since `T` and `e` in `is_in_tailrec` are always the same as `T` and `e` in `is_in`, this can be rewritten as

```
def is_in[T](e: T, as: List[T]) : Boolean = {
  @tailrec
  def is_in_tailrec(as: List[T], acc: Boolean): Boolean = as match {
    case Nil     => acc;
    case x :: xs => is_in_tailrec(xs, e == x || acc)
  }

  is_in_tailrec(as, false)
}
```

Comment: In your first posting you have the following line in the end ... is_in_tailrec(e, as, false). Is this for initialisation purpose? My thoughts are that acc is initialized with false at the beginning in this line. Then it could happen that either the list is empty in the beginning, which means false is returned immediately or the list is not empty, then there is a check if e == x, if yes, then true is returned and if no we have the false from the initialization. So, if the element for which we are looking for is not in the list in the end, then false is returned. Is this correct?

Comment: are my thoughts correct this way in my previous comment or did I miss something?